# Angular 4 custom component using material date picker

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a custom control that includes the date picker for angular. I can't seem to get the validation to fire correctly to enable/disable the submit button. One of the customization's added is to let the user enter 8 digits and then attempt to parse that as a date. If the user enters the same date twice then the submit button will stay disabled even though the required indication in the control is gone. Here is a stackblitz that demonstrates the issue:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8xstpw

I am sure that I am wiring something up wrong, but can't track it down yet. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Looks like your Stackblitz is using the wrong version of Angular. Update `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk` to the latest version (`5.0.0-rc.0`). You're also missing the theming import.

Comment: @Edric I updated to the latest versions and imported the theme and it still behaves the same. I have determined that part of the problem is validate() is called before onKey() which is changing the value, but after the validate is called.